# How to get Z values from Z Buffer

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, zbuffer

I'm having problems with drawing in OpenGL and I need to see exactly what values are being placed in the depth buffer. Can anyone tell me how to retrieve these values?
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) with format = GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, for example:

```
float depth;
glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
```

Will get the depth of pixel (0, 0).

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there anyway to print a debug statement if the value in the depth buffer is changed rather than having to print out a frame of pixels each render loop?

Comment: There is: Occlusion Query.