# How to pass depth buffer from OGRE to CUDA?

Tags: opengl, cuda, ogre, depth-buffer

I am using [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) for rendering some objects. At every frame, I would like to pass the resulting depth buffer to CUDA for running some kernels on it and computing a result.

How can I achieve this? How do I get access to the depth buffer in OGRE? How do I pass this to CUDA for processing? I do not need to write to the depth buffer in the CUDA kernels, it can be read-only.

Comment: I don't believe you can get direct access to the depth buffer. But you might be able to render it to a texture and access the texture in a CUDA kernel. Also why cross post this on [SO] and Game Development?

Comment: @talonmies: Hoping someone at gamedev knows about OGRE :)

Answer (score 2):

Passing buffers from Ogre to CUDA is possible like this:

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 mDevice;
renderWindow->getCustomAttribute("D3DDEVICE", (void*) &mDevice);

Ogre::HardwareVertexBufferSharedPtr vbuf =
    renderOp.vertexData->vertexBufferBinding->getBuffer(0); // or where your vertexData is stored.

Direct3DVertexBuffer9*  mD3D9VertexBuffer_1 =
static_cast<Ogre::D3D9HardwareVertexBuffer*>(vbuf.get())->getD3D9VertexBuffer();
```

Now you can do a cudaMemcopy(). More info: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=47003&sid=a0b22c741f015e2fdf0a5862d12d2020&start=25

I have this working for the vertex buffer. I am not sure if this works correctly with a DepthBuffer, but at least you can try: `IDirect3DSurface9* Ogre::D3D9Device::getDepthBuffer  ( D3D9RenderWindow *  renderWindow )`. However I cannot find Information if this works or not (see http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1D3D9Device.html#a8e195a845ed22e0215d42abbc75d744e)

Comment: Corjin: Thanks. I'm on Linux, so OpenGL :)

Comment: I see your tag now. I don't have experience with that. However, maybe you can combine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499999/how-to-get-z-values-from-z-buffer and http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=296902. I cannot provide support, but maybe it is worthwhile to have look at it.

Comment: @Corjin: Thanks a lot. You've given enough leads to me to try an OpenGL solution :)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find a way to do this with OpenGL :(